# Create rolling array_agg column over 10-day period

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to do create a column with a rolling array agg over a 10 day period.

I table a table with:

```
row_id | date_end    | user_id | item_id
1186     '2017-11-06'  3908805   158
59801    '2017-11-16'  3249668   157
59800    '2017-11-16'  3249668   158
59802    '2017-11-16'  3249668   158
59799    '2017-11-16'  3249668   157
61678    '2017-11-17'  3249668   158
61679    '2017-11-17'  3249668   157
```

I want to create a **rolling** aggregate array (`array_agg`) of the `item_id` with respect to upcoming 10-day window.

Currently I have tried:

```
select a.row_id, a.date_end, a.user_id, array_agg(b.item_id)
from table1 as a
join table1 as b on a.row_id = b.row_id
and b.date_end between (a.date_end - interval '10 days') and a.date_end
group by a.row_id, a.date_end, a.user_id
order by a.row_id, a.date_end
```

but this is not aggregating the `item_id` into an array. Only appends a single int value.

Sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/696ed/4/0

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: What does the expected output look like? What do you need to group by?

Comment: Expected output should be: `row_id | date_end | user_id | item_id | array_agg` - so that for each `row_id` you should have an array_agg of the items that the `user_id` has purchased in the 7 day window.

Comment: There is no column for `visitor_id`. Also, if you want to see all the columns in your result, what do you wish to aggregate on?

Comment: sorry! edit made to that comment. All the columns are not necessary as long as `row_number` is still there so that I can join to original table. I want array agg to be an array of the `item_id` for each `user_id` over the 10-day window.

Comment: `row_number` is not a good idea for aggregation since the rows might be aggregated. If you really need one, then you can choose to get the `MAX` or `MIN` row id but just be aware that you will not get all the row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the groupings you need, this should get you the results you need:

```
select a.date_end, a.user_id, array_agg(b.item_id)
from table1 as a
join table1 as b on a.row_id = b.row_id
and b.date_end between (a.date_end - interval '10 days') and a.date_end
group by a.date_end, a.user_id
order by a.date_end
```

You need to `GROUP BY` on the columns that you need aggregated. If you group by all the columns then you will not get the aggregation.

Comment: This yields an array agg of the `item_id` bought over the 10 day period. I am hoping to have an array agg of the `item_id` bought by __each__ `user_id` with respect to the 10 day window.

Comment: Updated based on your comment.